# Why are my intlist values not increasing, or why doesn't the ellipse() function respond to it?

Tags: java, processing, ellipse

javascript code in processing 3.5.3 not working, not sure why. It's supposed to create circles and have them bounce around the screen, instead it makes the right amount of circles but they don't move. It seems like intlist.set() isn't working, but I'm not sure why. Help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

int x = 200;
int y = 150;
int b = 50;

float slope = -1;

int numOfCircles = 10;

IntList initPosX = new IntList();
IntList initPosY = new IntList();

IntList exes = new IntList();
IntList whys = new IntList();

IntList xSpeeds = new IntList();
IntList ySpeeds = new IntList();

void setup()
{

  numOfCircles = int(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "How many circles ya want?"));
  size(800,400);
  for(int i = 0; i < numOfCircles; i++)
  {
    int toAddX = int(random(0,400));
    initPosX.append(toAddX);

    int toAddY = int(random(0,300));
    initPosY.append(toAddY);

    exes.append(0);//(int(random(-30,30)));
    whys.append(0);//(int(random(-30,30)));

    xSpeeds.append(1);
    ySpeeds.append(1);    
  }
}
void draw()
{
  background(100,100,100,255);
  for(int i = 0; i < numOfCircles; i++)
  {
    ellipse(exes.get(i) + initPosX.get(i), whys.get(i) + initPosY.get(i), 20, 20);
    exes.set(i, i + xSpeeds.get(i));
    whys.set(i, i + ySpeeds.get(i));
    if(exes.get(i) > width || exes.get(i) <= 0)
    {
      print("side wall hit");
      xSpeeds.set(i, i*= slope);
    }
    if(whys.get(i) > height || whys.get(i) <= 0)
    {
      print("roof hit");
      ySpeeds.set(i, i*= slope);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And you are sure you are writing code in javascript?

Comment: This isn't JavaScript

Comment: The first thing you need to do is [debug your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). What is the value of `exes` before and after you set the `i` element?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant java not javascript lol

Comment: If this is supposed to be Java it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at those lines:

```
exes.set(i, i + xSpeeds.get(i));
whys.set(i, i + ySpeeds.get(i));
```

What you want to do there, is add the speed to the current value of exes/whys at the index i.
But what you are actually doing is set them to the index + the speed.
Since the index is never going to change, neither are the positions.

To fix this, replace it with this:

```
exes.set(i, exes.get(i) + xSpeeds.get(i));
whys.set(i, whys.get(i) + ySpeeds.get(i));
```

**Update**

When changing just this, your code still won't work properly, because the collision detection:

```
if(exes.get(i) > width || exes.get(i) <= 0)
{
  print("side wall hit");
  xSpeeds.set(i, i*= slope);
}
if(whys.get(i) > height || whys.get(i) <= 0)
{
  print("roof hit");
  ySpeeds.set(i, i*= slope);
}
```

does not detect collision for the actual position, because that would be the position (exes, whys) + the initPos's, so it should be

```
if (exes.get(i) + initPosX.get(i) > width || exes.get(i) + initPosX.get(i) <= 0)
{
   //the code
}
if (whys.get(i) + initPosY.get(i) > height ||  whys.get(i) + initPosY.get(i) <= 0)
{
   //the code
}
```

If you were to start it now however, you would get an error. That is because you changing to something negative. instead of `i*= slope` just use `int(i * slope)` (because int * float returns a float, you have to convert the result to an int by using [int()](https://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html)).

Furthermore, you again don't actually want the index, but the current value at the index:

```
xSpeeds.set(i, int(xSpeeds.get(i) * slope); //the same for ySpeeds
```

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes sometimes. Also, if an answer helped you, you can accept it. For more details, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I changed the code accordingly, but it still doesn't work actually.  The circles are now moving, but they don't respond to walls at all. Instead, the last circle to touch a wall is the only one that responds to it, and it bounces super late, then drags all the other circles with it instead of moving them independantly. Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please also note that I fixed my first answer (I wrote "exes" instead of "whys")

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you a ton, I completely forgot about the offset.